# ASP.NET Global.asax Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

My question is, is there another way like in a class level location that I can execute all of application methods that are in the Global.cs such as "Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute"oal is that  or "Application_Start"? The main goal is that I want to hide all these applictions methods in to the compiled dll of the application and take them out of the  Global.cs.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not control application execution flow for single aspx/single class level. Because for all classes , there is single application and that goes through request pipeline ( prerequest handler, request etc..). That is why we have HTTPModule to intercept those pipeline event.

But anyway, i think you can apply filter in those events, that if request is for abc.aspx, then only execute XYZ for that class only.

Following link , might be more helpful - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your methods in Global.ascx into "one-liners" that call an API exposed in your dll. For example `Application_Start()` can call `myClass.ApplicationStart()` and `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute` can call `myClass.PreRequestHandlerExecute`. Simply define `public static myClass` in your application namespace and decide on your API. Then import the `myClass` namespace in your `Global.cs`.